# Не считает по формуле в БД MS Access

Tags: ms-access, report

Создаю вычисляемое поле в отчёте по формуле =[остаток на начало дня]+[приход]-[расход] но в отчёте не считает почему-то данные
На 1 скриншоте отображён отчёт, на втором как у меня в конструкторе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *Создаю вычисляемое поле в отчёте по формуле =[остаток на начало дня]+[приход]-[расход]* - а откуда они, эти поля? из запроса-источника данных? или это поля формы/отчёта? В любом случае правильно - считать это значение непосредственно в запросе.

Comment: @Akina Эти данные есть в таблице (определённые поля). Из них я формирую новое поле в отчёте. Но оно не считается

Comment: Таблица - недоступна! Доступны только поля запроса - источника данных.